# help with nand circuit

Tags: logic

I tried to make a circuit from this expression but it's not working right.
Here's the expression and circuit:

#### Expression

$$\overline{\overline{P_1.S_1}.\overline{P_2.\left(\overline{\overline{P_1}.\overline{\overline{S_1}.\overline{S_2}}}\right)}}$$

[image: circuit]

Comment: Why are you claiming it does not work right?

Comment: Could be that it's first time i'am using. Do you know why output shows a letter sometimes? it should be only 1 and 0, no?

Comment: I would write a truth table, try all zeros and all ones by hand in the expression and see that you get. Then an alternating 0-1 and 1-0 pattern since there are only four inputs.

Comment: i did that but for example when P2 is 1 and others 0 it gives a letter in red what means a error i think.

Comment: I mean what do you get when you do them by hand - before simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks right to me, perhaps the problem is in one of the connections, or the way you are using the software.